# Matching Game. Javascript. DOM lastChild

Tags: javascript

There is a simple game. The left and right sides are identical, except for one thing: the left side has one extra face. The user needs to find out and click on that extra face (lastChild). It will trigger the function to double the face quantity.

The problem is - all the faces in my game are lastChild. Where is the problem?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Matching Game. Part 3.</title>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #rightSide {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }

  </style>

  <script>

function generateFaces(){

  var numberOfFaces = 5;
  //var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    for(var i=0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var smileImage = document.createElement("img");
        smileImage.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";

        var topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()* 400) + 1;
        var leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()* 400) + 1;

        smileImage.style.top = topPosition + "px";
        smileImage.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
        leftSide.appendChild(smileImage);

    var leftSideImages = leftSide.cloneNode(true);
    leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
    rightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

    leftSide.lastChild.style.background = "red";

    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    leftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    numberOfFaces += 5;
    generateFaces();
    }          
    }
}  


</script>

</head>

<body onload = "generateFaces()">
   <h1>Matching Game</h1>
   <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>

   <div id="leftSide"></div>

   <div id="rightSide"></div>     

</body>    

</html>
```

Comment: `leftSide` variable not defined in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your click event to every element in the loop. You first need to over-ride the previous handler and then re-bind it to the last element.

```js
function generateFaces(){

  var numberOfFaces = 5;
  var leftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var rightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
    for(var i=0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var smileImage = document.createElement("img");
        smileImage.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";

        var topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()* 400) + 1;
        var leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()* 400) + 1;

        smileImage.style.top = topPosition + "px";
        smileImage.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
        leftSide.appendChild(smileImage);

    var leftSideImages = leftSide.cloneNode(true);
    leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
    rightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

    leftSide.lastChild.style.background = "red";

    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];         
    }
    var pics = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(i=0;i<pics.length;i++){
     pics[i].onclick = function() {
       return false;
     }
    }
    leftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    numberOfFaces += 5;
    generateFaces();
    } 
}
```

```css
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #rightSide {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<body onload = "generateFaces()">
   <h1>Matching Game</h1>
   <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>

   <div id="leftSide"></div>

   <div id="rightSide"></div>     

</body>
```